# Variable as object key does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uej6064u/3/)

```
var json = {name: 'chan'};
var variable = 'age';

$.extend(json, {[variable]: 35});

$('#result').html(JSON.stringify(json));
```

This method works on most popular browsers except IE, I need to define object key dynamically, how to make it work on IE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `[]` notation for property names in object initializers is an ES2015 feature, and older versions of Internet Explorer don't support it. (Older versions of *all* browsers don't support it; there are lots of mobile devices that would also consider that an error.)

You can however use `[ ]` in a property assignment expression:

```
json[variable] = 35;
```

That should work everywhere.

Comment: thanks, if I want to add more object should be `json[variable] = {age: 35: height 180};`, right?

Comment: @Chan that will set the value of one single property to that object. I will extend the answer.

Comment: @Chan well now I am not sure I understand your question. If you want to set the properties "age" and "height" on the `json` object, you can use `$.extend()` with that object literal.

Comment: never mind ha, I just need to remember better not use `{[variable]: 35}` format, may I ask one more question, in the past I remembered if I don't clear the last comma in array of object, it will be error in IE, for example, `var arrs = ['a', 'b',];`, I just find out IE 11 is fine with that, is it ok right now?

Comment: @Chan yes new versions of IE are OK with extra `,` at the end of the list - **BUT** IE may interpret that differently!  Try `["a", "b",].length` - in IE that *might* be `3` instead of `2`!

Answer (score 2):

Just do that: `json[variable] = 35` instead of `$.extend(json, {[variable]: 35});`.

This should work in IE.